# Can we create Fail over clustering using sql server 2012 standard edition on amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2012

We are planing to move on amazon's EC2 services.
So my question is that can we create fail over clustering on amazon EC2 using sql server 2012 standard edition ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon EC2 is just a virtual server that you can run Windows or Linux on. If you have the skills required to setup SQL Server fail over then you should be able to create this on EC2.

You might want to also look at [Amazon RDS Multi-AZ deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/multi-az/), which manage a backup database server for you, and fail over to the backup server automatically. For SQL Server, [Amazon RDS supports SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/) 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 including Express, Web, Standard and Enterprise editions.